# Multiple views with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I am trying to display multiple views in angular to help fix the footer problem I am having with this site I am building. I want to make sure that what I have been reading about and trying to mimic is making sense. This is what I have so far.

index.html

```
<!--Do not code below this line-->
<main ng-view="header"></main>
<main ng-view="body"></main>
<main ng-view="footer"></main>
```

routes.js file

```
angular.module('appRoutes', ['ngRoute'])

.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        views: {
            'header': {
                temmplateUrl: 'app/views/header.html'
            },
            'body':   {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/body.html'
            },
            'footer': {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/footer.html'
            }
        }
    })
```

I have it working where I have just one view and have my header and footer inside the index.html file but I saw that you can have multiple views and really just switch out the "body" view with other pages.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: you are looking to use ui-router, not ng-route. I dont think ng route supports multiple ng-views https://ui-router.github.io/

Comment: Ahh ok cool I will push the original again to github just to make sure I have a back up copy and change all my routes to use $stateprovider. I really need to learn the difference between ngRoute and ui-router so that I can better decide how I want to build out from now on. i will be sure to update this when I have it working to just help other newbies.

Comment: the beauty about ui-router is you can embed views inside of views inside of views etc

Answer (score 1):

To display multiple views you could use only ng-include.
See  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude for more ngInclude details.
Here is a example: (notice the wrap in single quotes)

```
<div id="header">
    <div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
</div>
<div id="content" ng-view></div>
<div id="footer">
    <div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Use ngRoute with ng-view to define a region (e.g div#content) where will be changed the dynamic content (as partial html).
See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView for more ngRoute details.

Good luck!

Comment: inside the single quotes is that the route to the page as in you have that view just inside the main folder or in my case do I insert the route to the template in there as in my case it would be 
    `<div id="footer">
    <div ng-include=" 'apps/views/templates/users/footer.html' "> </div>`

Comment: Exactly, ng-include finds by relative path. In addition, ng-include does "get resource", therefore maybe restricted by browser's CORS policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can have just one `ng-view`.

You can change its content in several ways: `ng-include`, `ng-switch` or mapping different controllers and templates through the routeProvider.

Alternatively, use [ui-router](http://You%20can%20have%20just%20one%20ng-view.%20%20You%20can%20change%20its%20content%20in%20several%20ways:%20ng-include,%20ng-switch%20or%20mapping%20different%20controllers%20and%20templates%20through%20the%20routeProvider.)